# ¿Cómo puedo solver 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list' '?

Tags: python

Estoy intentado hacer una operación en la cual cree una lista y de ahí por cada valor de la lista se debe realizar la operación.
Después debe mostrar cada valor dado por cada argumento.
No se cuál es mi error, soy nueva en programación.

Mi código es:

```py
g = 9.8
m = 0.0135
Dt = 0.033
vi = (0.910,1.051,1.142,1.198,1.269,1.336,1.392,1.447,1.519,1.615,1.678,1.708,1.825,1.872,1.712,1.99,1.517,1.440,1.403)

def k(vi):
    k = m * g/[vi]
    for n in [vi]:
        k (vi)

print(k(vi))
```

Al ejecutarlo recibo este error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-46ddff37e440> in <module>
----> 1 print(k(vi))

<ipython-input-57-1fec2e33173a> in k(vi)
      1 def k(vi):
----> 2     k = m * g/[vi]
      3     for n in [vi]:
      4         k (vi)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list'
```

Comment: Estás haciendo esto: `9.8 / [(0.910, 1.051, 1.142, ...)]` Obviamente vas a tener ese mensaje de error al intentar dividir un numero (int o float) entre una lista.

Comment: okey, pero como hago para se tome un valor de esa lista y se realize el procedimiento, que me de cada resultado con cada valor de la lista

Comment: Con una comprensión de lista `k=[m*g/n for n in vi]`. Por cierto la recursión no es muy buena

Comment: `vi = (0.910,1.051,1` es una tupla, no una lista.

Answer (score 0):

Analicemos los problemas del código:

```
vi = (0.910,1.051,1.142,1.198,1.269,1.336,1.392,1.447,1.519,1.615,1.678,1.708,1.825,1.872,1.712,1.99,1.517,1.440,1.403)
```

Esto crea una *tupla*, no una *lista*. Las tuplas son inmutables; una vez creadas no pueden ser modificadas. Si solo las vas a usar sin modificar, no hay diferencia, pero si planeas agregar, modificar o eliminar elementos, tiene que ser una lista.

La función

```
def k(vi):
    k = m * g/[vi]
    for n in [vi]:
        k (vi)
```

no tiene ningun `return algo`, por lo que nunca retorna nada. Además tiene una llamada recursiva que no se justifica ni se explica.

**Cómo hacerlo**

Una aproximación sencilla es crear una lista vacia a la que se agregan los resultados de evaluar la función para cada elemento de la otra lista. Luego retornas esa lista.

```
def k(vi):
    salida = []
    for n in vi:
        k = m * g / n
        salida.append(k)
    return salida
```

Pero se puede simplificar usando *comprensión de listas*. Esta expresión es equivalente al ciclo `for` anterior:

```
salida = [m * g / n for n in vi]
```

La parte `m * g / n` se calcula para cada valor de `vi`. El interprete extrae el valor, lo asigna a la variable `n`, calcula la expresión y agrega el valor a la lista en formación.

La expresión la podemos colocar directamente en el `return`, con lo que la función se reduce a

```
def k(vi):
    return [m * g / n for n in vi]
```